# Configure Scala Script in IntelliJ IDE to run a spark standalone script through spark-submit

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I want to run a standalone Spark script that I've already compiled with `sbt package` command. How could I set the right configuration of Scala Script to run my script in IntelliJ IDE? Currently I'm using the command line with the following command to run it(but I want to run in IntelliJ to further debugging, for example):

`~/spark-1.2.0/bin/spark-submit --class "CoinPipe" target/scala-2.10/coinpipe_2.10-1.0.jar /training/data/dir 7 12`

Bellow is a snapshot of what I'm trying to do:
[image: The figure shows how I'm trying to configure my script to run in IntelliJ]

Comment: Here is a 2 step solution where you run spark-submit and then run the debugger in Intellij: http://www.bigendiandata.com/2016-08-26-How-to-debug-remote-spark-jobs-with-IntelliJ/

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this post is old, but I ran into the same problem and found a solution so figured I'd post it here.

- Create a java application run configuration with main class:

  ```
  org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
  ```
- VM options should include the classpath of spark conf and jars, at a minimum:

  ```
  -cp "c:\spark\conf\;c:\spark\jars\*"
  ```
- Program arguments should contain your jar file as the first argument, followed by the actual program arguments that you wish to pass to your program:

  ```
  yourapp.jar arg1 arg2
  ```
- Use classpath of module should be set to your module.

[image]

Comment: I correctly chose my module but My IDE showed "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit not found in module ". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Install sbt plugins: Goto File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install IntelliJ Plugins -> Search for sbt and install it.
2. After sbt plugin install, restart intellij and Start New Scala sbt project (File -> New Project -> Scala -> SBT).
3. Now open up the build.sbt file and add the all the dependencies.
4. Now Create a new Scala class in src -> main -> scala and type in your code.
5. Right click and hit Run.

**NOTE :** You might want to restart intelliJ sometime to get the dependencies pulled from the build.sbt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup spark-submit as an [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/external-tools.html?origin=old_help).  It won't be in the run menu, though.